# Changing behavior of EditTextPreference when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to change the behavior of a EditTextPreference for my needs.
It hold a path i set using an intent.
My problem is it also open his own Fragment to modify his text.
I end up with 2 consecutives windows: the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE which i wanted and the default windows to write a simple string in a box.

Here the SettingFragment.java:

```
@Override
public  void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

    Preference editTextPreference = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("path");
    if (editTextPreference != null) {
        editTextPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                Intent secondActivity = new Intent(ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                startActivityForResult(secondActivity, RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) {
        Uri treeUri = data.getData();
        System.out.println(treeUri.toString());
        String path = FileUtil.getFullPathFromTreeUri(treeUri, getContext());

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("path",path).apply();
    }
}
```

Here the associated xml:

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory>
    <EditTextPreference
        app:key="path"
        app:title="@string/path_title"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
    />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I tried changing EditTextPreference for Preference but the value woulnd't show anymore. I've found out that useSimpleSummaryProvider could only be applied to ListPreference and EditTextPreference.
I also tried to disable it but it would no longer fire onPreferenceClick().
Is there a way to only execute onPreferenceClick rather than the default fragment or a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around the problem, sort of, using Preference instead of EditTextPreference. So now it only open up ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.
Then i used this code to set the summary i need:

```
Preference editPreference = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("path");
editPreference.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("path", "Le chemin n'est pas défini"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
    public boolean setOnPreferenceClickListener(Preference preference) {
        if(preference.getKey().equals("path")){
           Intent secondActivity = new Intent(ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
           startActivityForResult(secondActivity, RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still getting both fragments opening. I think the issue is me adding a new eventListener and the "default" one still being fired.

Comment: Could you please try with OnPreferenceClickListener as mentioned in the edit ?